# Java - Html special chars

Tags: java, html, xpath, utf-8, htmlcleaner

I want to make some XPath request on a HTML file. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try{

        /** We load the HTML file we want to parse */  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream("html_doyoubuzz.html"),"UTF-8"));


        /** we clean HTML file */           
        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(br);
        Document doc2 = new DomSerializer( new CleanerProperties() ).createDOM(tagNode);


        /******************************
         *                            *
         *       XPath Requests       *
         *                            *
         ******************************/

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        Object dates_experience = xpath.evaluate("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/h4/span[2]", doc2, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) dates_experience;
        String s;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            s = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
            System.out.println(s); 
        }



    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My HTML file is encoded in UTF-8 (as written in the meta tag). My problem is the output. I get this:

```
d?cembre 2010 - d?cembre 2010)
f?vrier 2010 - juin 2010)
juillet 2009 - septembre 2009)
juin 2009 - juin 2009)
juillet 2008 - ao?t 2008)
```

instead of this, which is my desired output:

```
décembre 2010 - décembre 2010)
février 2010 - juin 2010)
juillet 2009 - septembre 2009)
juin 2009 - juin 2009)
juillet 2008 - août 2008)
```

Do you have any idea to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML file is UTF-8? I mean, windows by default uses its own encoding when saving files. Eclipse itself uses that encoding by default

Comment: How can I be sure ? By the way, the meta tag indicates that the charset is UTF-8.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, and the HTML file is inside your project, you can select the file in the explorer view and press alt+Enter (or right click and the select properties). It will open a window where you can check the Text encoding. The beta tag is the way you declare the encoding you are going to use, but it does not force the OS to use it. That responsibility is yours

Comment: I checked. UTF-8 is used.

Comment: There are (at least) two separate issues here: (a) what bytes are being emitted by the program, and (b) how that data looks when you view it in some program (including, what encodings and fonts that program is configured to use). To separate these issues, it could be helpful to have your output sent to a file, then use a hex editor to examine the bytes in the file. Then you'll know whether the failure is in (a) or (b).

Comment: I tried with hexEdit, i have "EF BF BD" instead of "é"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I opened my html file with hexEdit and I saw some curious bytes: "EF BF BD".

It was because I did a right click/copy/paste of the html code. I had to change the way I loaded my html file.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean output in java console, you can change console encoding. Console encoding is default operation system encoding. You can change in eclipse below link.

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

If you don't use eclipse you can add system parameters for windows

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

also you can try

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: If i do your first solution, i obtain this: d�cembre 2010 - d�cembre 2010). If I do the system.setout, i obtain this: dï¿½cembre 2010 - dï¿½cembre 2010)

Comment: Plus, I tried to write the output into a file and I have the same problem :(

Comment: My suggestions ara printing to java console. If you want to file my suggestions not work for you. In your problem this new FileInputStream("html_doyoubuzz.html"),"UTF-8") should be enough.